# sqlite sum() of French decimal format numbers

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum, decimal-point

When I realize this type of SQLite SQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(Column) as TOTAL_DEBIT FROM table_name;
```

I expect the addition of real but it gives me sum of integer division of numbers.

For exemple:

```
SELECT SUM(DEBIT) as TOTAL_DEBIT FROM DEBIT
```

The SQL query on the table below gives that:

```
TOTAL_DEBIT
11475
```

I wish I get this kind of result:

```
TOTAL_DEBIT
11482,79
```

Example Table :

```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "DEBIT";
   CREATE TABLE "DEBIT" ("DATE" DATETIME NOT NULL , "DEBIT" REAL NOT NULL );
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('23/12/13','29,90');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('23/12/13','304,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('15/01/14','1245,48');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/01/14','304,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('23/01/14','30,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('28/01/14','129,10');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('31/01/14','32,10');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/02/14','30,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/02/14','304,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('17/03/14','117,66');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/03/14','30,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/03/14','304,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('02/04/14','175,62');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/04/14','304,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('23/04/14','30,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('30/04/14','32,10');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/05/14','304,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/05/14','2838,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/05/14','30,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('30/05/14','145,41');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('23/06/14','30,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('23/06/14','304,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('25/06/14','112,48');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/07/14','304,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/07/14','30,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('24/07/14','1245,48');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('25/07/14','127,68');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('31/07/14','32,10');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('12/08/14','23,89');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/08/14','30,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/08/14','304,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('10/09/14','480,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/09/14','30,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/09/14','304,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('29/09/14','131,37');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/10/14','30,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/10/14','304,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('24/10/14','96,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('31/10/14','32,50');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/11/14','304,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('24/11/14','30,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('28/11/14','143,92');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/12/14','30,00');
   INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/12/14','304,00');
```

Thank you in advance for your help and best regards,
Alban

Comment: Ah! The problem comes from the French decimal format:
In France it is the comma is used to separate the real numbers.
The international format uses a period as a separator.

Comment: Is the number stored in a character format?

Comment: Another difficulty would be if there are already periods `.` (marking off thousands, millions, etc.) in the format. In that case a simple `REPLACE()` as described below won't work.

Comment: The table you show uses REAL. So why do you insert strings at all? Insert numeric values, such as 29.90 instead of '29,90' and there should be no problem. Unfortunately SQLite is not very strict about datatypes to say the least, so once you enter strings, it will most likely store strings instead of numbers rather than raise an exception. And as it seems it doesn't even error on summing the strings, but simply takes the number the string starts with.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not `REPLACE` the `,` before you `SUM` then re `REPLACE` it?

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUM(REPLACE(DEBIT,',','.')),'.',',') AS TOTAL_DEBIT 
FROM DEBIT
```

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are stored as text, then you can do the following (I would not depend on implicit conversion):

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUM(CAST(REPLACE(debit, ',', '.') AS REAL)), '.', ',') AS total_debit
  FROM debit
```

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten that the French decimal separator is different from the international decimal system: when the comma is replaced by a point it works very well :

SQL Query :

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(DEBIT),2) as amount FROM DEBIT;
```

works very good with this SQL script :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "DEBIT";
CREATE TABLE "DEBIT" ("DATE" DATETIME NOT NULL , "DEBIT" REAL NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('23/12/13','29.90');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('23/12/13','304.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('15/01/14','1245.48');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/01/14','304.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('23/01/14','30.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('28/01/14','129.10');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('31/01/14','32.10');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/02/14','30.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/02/14','304.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('17/03/14','117.66');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/03/14','30.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/03/14','304.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('02/04/14','175.62');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/04/14','304.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('23/04/14','30.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('30/04/14','32.10');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/05/14','304.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/05/14','2838.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/05/14','30.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('30/05/14','145.41');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('23/06/14','30.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('23/06/14','304.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('25/06/14','112.48');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/07/14','304.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/07/14','30.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('24/07/14','1245.48');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('25/07/14','127.68');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('31/07/14','32.10');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('12/08/14','23.89');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/08/14','30.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/08/14','304.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('10/09/14','480.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/09/14','30.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/09/14','304.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('29/09/14','131.37');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/10/14','30.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/10/14','304.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('24/10/14','96.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('31/10/14','32.50');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('21/11/14','304.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('24/11/14','30.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('28/11/14','143.92');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/12/14','30.00');
INSERT INTO "DEBIT" VALUES('22/12/14','304.00');
```

Comment: You should not rely on reginal settings at all. A date is a date and should be entered in the ISO format 'yyyy-mm-dd', to be recognized irrespective of any region setting. Same for numbers. Numbers are not strings. So neither enter '20.90' nor '29,90' but 29.90 without quotes.